# Create PGP key to use with ObjectivePGP in iOS app

Tags: ios, objective-c, encryption, pgp, openpgp

I'm making an application that needs encrypt/decrypt GPG messages but it needs generate its own keys (public/private).

I'm using [ObjectivePGP](https://github.com/krzyzanowskim/ObjectivePGP) and it works great, but it doesn't generate the keys by itself (or I don't know how to do it), so I need to generate it via command line with [gpg](https://gpgtools.org/) or some online tools.

My question is: Is there some way to create these keys inside my app? Maybe some framework with appstore friendly license.

Notes:

I've tried with `UNNetPGP`, but it doesn't work when I try to encrypt messages with public keys generated by other applications or decrypt messages encrypted by these applications. I have even tried just use `UNNetPGP` just to generate the keys and import them to `ObjectivePGP`, but I receive messages like "Decrypt key doesn't exist" or similar (this doesn't happen when I use another keys).

Comment: no. ObjectivePGP does not have this part implemented, and UNNetPGP is not really maintained for a long time and has issues. As for today, trying to generate key with UNNetPGP and use it with ObjectivePGP is the right way to go. I'm author of Objective and did work with netpgp.

Comment: @Marcin , can you please explain me, how we can implement ObjectivePGP in our own application.

Comment: @Ravi See https://github.com/krzyzanowskim/ObjectivePGP#usage

Comment: @Marcin Thank you. In this document, he didn't provide the information which libraries and files we should add to project. can you please tell me that.

Comment: @Ravi the best option would be look into ObjectivePGP.podspec I'm affraid that manual installation is harder than via Cocoapods.

Comment: @Marcin is it ok that only ObjecivePGP.podspec  for our own applicaiton. sorry for disturbing. actually im trying this from last week on-words.

Comment: @Marcin can you please check my issue once http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41041030/pgp-encryption-integration-using-objectivepgp